# How to disable ESC to exit full screen in Mac catalyst (or in AppKit)

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, mac-catalyst

Our App is a fullscreen app, but user can still exit fullscreen mode by press ESC, I wonder how to disable ESC to exit fullscreen, and disable cmd+ctrl+f to enter fullscreen